# Configparser doesn't open a file object

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

Accordingly to [configparser documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.read_file) it should be possibile to

> Read and parse configuration data from f which must be an iterable yielding Unicode strings (for example files opened in text mode)

But I can't make it read a file previously assigned into a variable:

```
>>> import configparser
>>> config = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> config.read_file(open('review-stats.cfg'))
>>> config.sections()
['global']
>>>
>>> config2 = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> f = open('review-stats.cfg')
>>> f
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='review-stats.cfg' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
>>> config2.read_file(f)
>>> config2.sections()
[]
```

Where am I wrong?

EDIT:
Not sure what happened, but the same steps now work as expected...

Comment: Are you using python 3.8.1?

Comment: no, 3.7:
```Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 19 2019, 22:52:49) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux```

Comment: the doc link in your post is of 3.8.1. I would suggest you to go through the documentation of 3.7 and try again.

Comment: The documentation for 3.7 says the same